# Make Graph Coloring less strict

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, graph-coloring

I'm experimenting with the [graph coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring) algorithm. That is a way of coloring the nodes of a graph such that no 2 adjacent nodes have the same color.

Suppose I have the following data I want to "color" (assign to groups), where each word is a node:

1. cat black
2. cat grey
3. dog grey
4. dog black

I would expect the following groups:

- cat, dog
- black, grey

But what if I add the name of my 4th animal, which is `grey` (just like the color)?
So the 4th line becomes:

4. dog black grey

The coloring algorithm couldn't distinguish between colors and names, so `black` and `grey` would end up in different groups.

How could I adjust the algorithm so that it becomes "less strict"?
Like: Only if 2 nodes appear in more than 90% together, consider them adjacent and put them in the same group.

*Note: The example I provided is simplified. I can't just group my words by `name` or `color`, so I need a more general approach.*

Answer (score 0):

(Hoping to get your question right - your example doesn't really help)

So currently you produce the following to-be-colored graph from your input data:

```
cat--black
 |   / |
 |  /  |
grey--dog
```

Now you could assign an integer label to each edge counting how often the corresponding pair appears together in a list item. Then you define some lower threshold and delete all edges labelled with a smaller number. If you now color the resulting graph, these "rare" pairs are again allowed a common color.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I need. But could you please provide a more detailed example? The number of edges can differ. The edge "cat-black" can occur, for example, once, while "cat-grey" can occur twice, etc.

Comment: If you give a more detailed description of your problem and possibly example, I can hopefully give you a more detailed answer.